# Angular2 is converting an Array to String

Tags: angular

I have some data coming from rest API where the model property of `myobject` is an array, but when I map it via creating service it converts it to string. Please see my code below.

```ts
  //from inteface =>
  export interface Car{
     make:string;
     model :Array<any>;
  }
  //from service => 
  getCars():Observable<Car[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._getUrl)
        .map(response=>response.json())
   }
  //from component= >
    this._carservice.getCars()
        .subscribe(cars=> {
            this.cars = cars;
            for(var i = 0; i<this.cars.length;i++){
                console.log(this.cars[i].Model)
            }
   });
  // OutPut 
  "Saloon,Estate,Coupe"
  //required OutPut
  [Saloon,Estate,Coupe]
```

Comment: The server probably sends it as string.

Comment: Thanks Günter, i forget to restart node after making changes to my model..i thought forever will take control of it.. Thanks a lot anyway..

Answer (score 1):

Issue on server side, The server was sending it as string..resolved by changing model in node